# Apple-like button style carousels in Drupal 7?

Tags: views

I would like to build a carousel which supports Apple-like scrolling, like at http://www.apple.com/displays/
So you would have a carousel with small "buttons" at the bottom which allow for easy navigation. The jcarousel module seems the preferred module for carousels, however it does not seem to support this type of carousel? I can not find a way to get links to all images/nodes/... to realise this via a different jcarousel template.
I did not find alternatives to carousel implementations in Drupal 7, but I might be mistaken of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module can do this and is stable for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

NivoSlider looks pretty much like that, but neither NivoSlider module has a stable D7 release. I'm currently using it on my personal site without any module - take a look at http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: I managed to solve this with slidesjs, although it's not fully Drupal integrated. Thanks for your suggestion!